# DRYing up functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three functions that follow up the same pattern, can anyone give me an idea on how to make this code DRY? The  child element with the css styles applied is not a child element, it is found way down the markup.

```
  $("#pills-ficha-tab").on("click", function(e){
    if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
      $(this).removeClass("active show");
      e.stopPropagation();
        $("#pills-ficha").removeClass("active show").css("display", "none");  

    } else {
        $("#pills-ficha").css("display", "block"); 
        $("#pills-ficha").siblings().css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $("#pills-candidato-tab").on("click", function(e){
    if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
      $(this).removeClass("active show");
      e.stopPropagation();
        $("#pills-candidato").removeClass("active show").css("display", "none"); 

    } else {
        $("#pills-candidato").css("display", "block"); 
        $("#pills-candidato").siblings().css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $("#pills-empresa-tab").on("click", function(e){
    if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
      $(this).removeClass("active show");
      e.stopPropagation();
        $("#pills-empresa").removeClass("active show").css("display", "none"); 

    } else {
        $("#pills-empresa").css("display", "block"); 
        $("#pills-empresa").siblings().css("display", "none"); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: More info would help with answering this question. Maybe post your HTML into a JSFiddle.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to turn your repeated code into a named function. The relationship between #pills-X-tab and #pills-X would determine how we do this. Are they parent and child? Then maybe `#pills-X-tab div` to select the child. Something more complicated? Then maybe pass the parent as a string then do string manipulation.

Comment: I did think about that as they are pretty far in the mark up and they are not related. Problem is, I am not sure how to capture the clicked element and then use $(this) on the named function, otherwise it would be easy to store the ID on a variable and then create another variable without the "-tab" part of the string...

Comment: Could you post a sample of HTML? It would help explain the usage of `siblings()` in the `false` case and not in the `true` case and also why `e.stopPropagation()` is only done in the `true` case.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tab-`id`s and the child-`id`s following a pattern, you can use the `id` of the clicked element minus the last 4 chars.

Also in order to not have to list all tabs when wiring up the event, I have added a parent div.

Demo:

```js
$("#tabs > span[id^='pills-']").on("click", function(e) {
  var relatedId = "#" + e.target.id.substring(0, e.target.id.length - 4);
  console.log(relatedId);
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active show");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(relatedId).removeClass("active show").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $(relatedId).css("display", "block");
    $(relatedId).siblings().css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <span id="pills-ficha-tab">Ficha</span> |
  <span id="pills-candidato-tab">Candidato</span> |
  <span id="pills-empresa-tab">Empresa</span>
</div>
```